# Unable to build entity manager factory ( JPA HIBERNATE )

Tags: java

When I am trying to run my application via JPA Hibernate , I receive some exceptions : 
( I added my pom.xml file and persistence.xml file below ... )

**My password in Mysql : root.**

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to build entity manager factory
at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:83)
at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:54)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
at ua.kiev.prog.sample2.App.main(App.java:9)
```

As I realize, I have problems below :

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling Driver#connect
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server
```

Help me to solve It.
Thanks in advance.

**My pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>ua.kiev.prog</groupId>
<artifactId>jpa-sample-2</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>jpa-sample-2</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.35</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.9.Final</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**My persistence.xml**

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0">
<persistence-unit name="JPATest">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver"
            value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
            value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jpasample2" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password"
            value="root" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect"
            value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Comment: Do you use maven?

Comment: You either a. haven't provided a suitable connection string or it is the wrong credentials etc. Using the same connection url can you connect with say a DB tool outside of your application?

Comment: @Wufo Yes, I use Maven

Comment: share your property file

Comment: So pls show your pom.xml

Comment: Does the db-server accepts tcp-connections with user "Root"?